# Integrate LoadRunner in Docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose, loadrunner

How can I integrate LoadRunner HP into Docker?

I have already tried installing Docker on a VM (virtual Machine) and followed the LoadRuner installation guide in order to understand those two.
But somehow I do not know what to do next.
Has anyone integrated LR into Docker, any tips?
Thank you!

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: I just wanna know if the LoadRunner can be integrated in Docker (actualy being asked to complete this task from work). And if it really can be integrated to find a solution and show them how. And somehow I got lost in the middle of this task .

Comment: Do you mean you want an LG docker? Because controller and VuGen docker don't make a lot of sense. IIRC there is a Linux docker image in the Linux install. I need to check it though.

Comment: I added an answer with the official LG docker image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some HP LoadRunner tutorials :
[https://www.guru99.com/loadrunner-v12-tutorials.html][1]

While here is a HP LoadRunner installation guide, and if you go to <kbd>page 32</kbd> you may found more details regarding your problem:

https://admhelp.microfocus.com/lr/en/12.56-12.57/help/PDFs/LoadRunner_Installation_Guide.pdf

The link above describes how to install the load generator on a Linux platform using Docker.

Create a custom Docker file using the sample below as a basis for your custom file. Once you have the file,follow these steps to build an image:
 1. Place your Dockerfile and the loadgenerator installation folder,VM(containing inst64.bin,unzip, andinstaller.sh),together in the same folder. 
2. Switch to root user. Make sure you have Internet access and the ability to install dependencies.
 3. In the directory which contains Dockerfile, type:

```
docker build -t load_generator ./
```

Import the base image with the next command :

```
docker load < load_generator.tar
```